# How to find the Euclidean norm of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, normed-spaces

I would like to know how to find the Euclidean norm of a complex number, like $10+i$ or $2-i$?

I would appreciate a clear and easy explanation with the necessary details.

Comment: Step 1: Look up the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_norm#Euclidean_norm_of_a_complex_number). Step 2: perform the simple calculation given in the definition.

Comment: $z=x+iy$ and read here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm_of_a_complex_number

Comment: |1+i|e=(1+i^2)^.5=1-1=0, but the answer is supposed to be 2. So we're multiplying by conjugate, why?

Comment: Very confused by what you wrote there.  What is e?  How did you get to (1+i^2)^.5 ?  As you said, you need to multiply by the conjugate.

Comment: Please phrase requests as requests, not orders. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For $x + iy \in \mathbb C$ the Euclidean norm is defined as $\| x + iy \| := \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Now you need to fill in the numbers and compute.

Comment: Ping me if you can't do it. But let me see some calculations first.

Comment: |1+i|=(1+i^2)^.5=1-1=0 Why are we multiplying by the conjugate?

Comment: @nnb: You are computing incorrectly: $1+i = 1+1i$, so $x=y=1$ in this case; the formula says $|1+i|=|1+1i| = \sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt{2}$. Multiplying by the conjugate accomplishes the same thing: $(1+i)(1-i) = 1^2-(i)^2 = 1^2-(-1) = 2$. More generally,$$(x+iy)(x-iy) = x^2 - (iy)^2 = x^2 -(-1)y^2 = x^2+y^2.$$

Comment: @nnb What Arturo said. Thanks, Arturo.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding an answer especially to clear up OP's confusion about multiplying conjugates and its relation with the Euclidean norm.

Let $a+b i$ be a complex number. Note that its euclidean norm, which I'll denote by $\| \cdot \|_e$, is given by $$\|a+bi\|_e=\sqrt {a^2+b^2}$$

Now what is the conjugate of $a+bi$? We know that it is given by  $\overline{a+bi}$ which equals $a-bi$.

So, $$\begin{align}(a+bi)(a-bi)&=a^2-abi+abi-b^2i^2\\ &=a^2-\not{abi}+\not{abi}+b^2 ~~~~\mbox{as $i^2=-1$}\\ &=\|a+bi\|_e^2\end{align}$$

So, to get its euclidean norm, it helps to multiply by its conjugate and take its positive square root.

> That is, for a complex number $z$, we have that $$\|z\|_e=\sqrt{z\bar z}$$ where $\bar z$ denotes the conjugate of $z$.